# get nested fields of Scala map

Tags: json, scala, scala-collections

I have the following Map Object :

```
val ad = node.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
```

and a printed example of ad object is:

```
ListMap(userId -> 1234, userName -> Jason, location -> ListMap(longitude -> -79.234264, latitude -> 37.2395), email -> Some(jason@yahoo.com))
```

I am trying to access the nested fields of the location field and cast it as a double. I have the following:

```
ad.get("location") match {
          case Some(i) => i match {
            case j: Map[Any, Any] => j("longitude").asInstanceOf[Double]
          }
```

My question is there another more graceful/cleaner syntax way to get the nested objects of the location field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the concept of "graceful/cleaner" because that kind of data structure doesn't smell good.

Anyway, the inner pattern match can be merged with the outer one, like this:

```
ad.get("location") match  {
    case Some(i: Map[Any,Any]) => i("longitude").asInstanceOf[Double]
    case _ => // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do anything graceful with a type like `Map[String, Any]`. I would consider using a more type-safe Json library in the first place, such as Circe.

Otherwise, it depends on what you know statically about your `Map`. If you know for certain that "location" exists in the `Map`, and that it always contains a nested `Map` with the "longitude" key, and that "longitude" is indeed always a `Double`, then it's OK to return a `Double`. Otherwise, you should consider returning an `Option[Double]` or something like `Either[String, Double]`. For example:

```
ad.get("location").flatMap {
  case location: Map[String, _] => Try(location("longitude").asInstanceOf[Double]).toOption
  case _ => None
}
```

This will return a `None` if the desired value cannot be obtained for whatever reason: "location" doesn't exist, "location" is not a map, the "location" map does not contain "longitude", etc.